# How to view diff when emacs suggests to recover this file?

Tags: buffers, saving, ediff

Sometimes it happens: emacs prompts you about recovering unsaved changes to a file, but you cannot remember if you want those changes or not.

Starting at the `recover-this-file` buffer, is there a way to view a diff or otherwise directly see the changes?

For example, something like what `magit-mode` gives when tabbing on a edited file in the status buffer.

Comment: Related: [On “really edit the buffer”, have emacs run ediff-current-file automatically?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19148/on-really-edit-the-buffer-have-emacs-run-ediff-current-file-automatically)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

After running `recover-this-file` and accepting the autosave version, you'll have a modified buffer containing the autosave contents. At this point you can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `diff-buffer-with-file` <kbd>RET</kbd> to see the differences between the modified buffer and the saved file.

The key I've bound for this actually runs a custom function, in order to produce a unified diff, and to skip the prompt for the buffer (it assumes the current buffer).

```
(defun my-diff-buffer-with-file ()
  "Compare the current modified buffer with the saved version."
  (interactive)
  (let ((diff-switches "-u")) ;; unified diff
    (diff-buffer-with-file (current-buffer))))
```

There's also an ediff equivalent (which I generally prefer, although I do use both) which is available at <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ediff-current-file` <kbd>RET</kbd>

If you wish to reject the modifications after checking the diff, you should be able to simply `undo` the recovery. (Failing that you can always use `revert-buffer` or `find-alternate-file`.)

As keybindings for diff commands often involve <kbd>=</kbd>, I find the following convenient (n.b. I've unbound the default `C-z` binding, and moved it instead to `C-z C-z`, which opens up `C-z` as a prefix for custom bindings):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z =") 'my-diff-buffer-with-file)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z C-=") 'ediff-current-file)
```

Comment: You mention ediff-current-file, and I find *almost* does this, and has several add'l features (figures out the auto-save file name, .  It's a builtin defined in ediff.el. C-h f ediff-current-file ... for info. Really should be an add'l command available from the recover-this-file buffer.  If I get one working better, I'll post.  (It - `M-x ediff-current-file n` -  sometimes worked when testing (it kinda works when the current buffer has changes) but does not work in the situation we're talking about.)