# How can I see the changes made to a modified buffer since the last save?

Tags: buffers, buffer-modified

Given a modified buffer, how can I diff it with the file backing it on disk to see what I've changed?

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [How to view diff when emacs suggests to recover this file?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3776/115)

Comment: There has been [the same question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49835/4319) at unix.stackexchange.com, but with less asnwers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You want the command <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>diff-buffer-with-file</kbd>. See the manual:

> diff-buffer-with-file is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in `diff.el'.
>
> ```
> (diff-buffer-with-file &optional BUFFER)
> ```
>
> View the differences between BUFFER and its associated file.
>   This requires the external program `diff` to be in your `exec-path`.

---

You may also be interested in `highlight-changes-mode` which automatically and interactively highlights changes made to the buffer after it was enabled.

Comment: Along the lines of `highlight-changes-mode` there's also the `diff-hl` package in GNU ELPA.

Comment: Yes, but right now it only works to show diffs between the (saved) buffer and a `vc` revision. I worked on diffing the _buffer_ (as opposed to its backing file) in [diff-hl #33](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/issues/33), but it's blocked on a bug in the Emacs core.

Comment: Do you have a bug-report number for that?

Comment: @Stefan, I haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: Got fixed a (probably) long time ago: works in 2019! :)

Answer (score 24):

Command `ediff-current-file`:

```
ediff-current-file is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
`ediff.el'.

(ediff-current-file)

Start ediff between current buffer and its file on disk.
This command can be used instead of `revert-buffer'.  If there is
nothing to revert then this command fails.
```

Comment: `ediff-current-file` has some benefits over `diff-buffer-with-file` if you want interactive review of changes rather than a plain diff. The interactive review even allows to selectively revert some parts, in case you finally don't want to save them. See also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3778/10614 for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is with the package [`line-reminder`](https://github.com/emacs-vs/line-reminder), which shows unsaved and saved changes in current session.  You can enable it globally with

```
(global-line-reminder-mode t)
```

or on a per-buffer basis with

```
(line-reminder-mode t)
```